# How can I release nsmuatablearray when back Viewcontroller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have 3 UIViewcontroller A(root viewcontroller ) ,B and C. I used below code to push Viewcontroller B from A.Do as same for pushing Viewcontrolller C from A.

```
BViewController *statusView = [[BViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *objNavigationController=[[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:statusView]autorelease];
[self presentViewController:objNavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];
[statusView release];
```

I created custom Back button and used below code to back ViewController A:

```
AViewController *chooseview = [[AViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@AController" bundle:nil];
}
UINavigationController *navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:chooseview];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navC animated:NO completion:nil];
[chooseview release];
```

And now, I want to release many array in ViewController B and C after I clicked on Back button. How can i do that? I tried use `[array release];` but after i return viewcontroller B, my app has crashed. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @trojanfoe: No, i dont use ARC.

Comment: Put [array release]; in your viewDidDisappear method in the view where you want to release this array

Comment: use ARC if possible, you are presenting view controller not pushing, you can use dismissViewControllerAnimated: method to go back,  release array in viewWillDisappear: method.

Comment: @JosonDaniel why you are intializing AViewController again in  BViewController. AViewController is already in memory. Try to reuse that or simple dismiss from BViewController. While dismiss view controller, there only release you object.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre: How can i dismiss it ? Can you please show me example code? thanks

Comment: Why not `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`?

Comment: To dismiss a ViewController you have to write this     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:nil];

Comment: @Cy-4AH: because in BViewController has tabcontroller. It has 4 sub viewcontroller. I tried [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; and dismissViewControllerAnimated: method but it can not back root view controller.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre: Yes, i tried but it can not back rootviewcontroller

Comment: you said  BViewController have sub view controller. Try with this     [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre: It still same. Can not back root view

Comment: Try to get BViewController and then call dismiss viewcontroller. Because you presented BViewController. so you need to dismiss with BViewController reference only.

Comment: @JosonDaniel, then use `[self.tabBarController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

I think u have to release your array In This Method

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  // Write Code here to release  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try put something like this

```
if ([array count] > 0) {
    [array release];
}

array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in `viewWillAppear` of your root view controller.

Comment: Why the `if ([array count] > 0)` test?

Comment: it's kind of "your array is not empty/it exists" so you can release smth)

Comment: or you can try smth like this `if (array != nil || [array count] != 0)`

Comment: You don't need to test; simply call `release` and assign the pointer (which you do afterwards anyway).

Comment: @trojanfoe what about memory leak?

Comment: @trojanfoe ohhh, sorry...my mistake :) i want to say about app crash...if try release empty array, before we create it..app will crash..or you assume that array was created in viewDidLoad?

Comment: You can `release` an empty array and you can `release` an unallocated array, so long as the pointer is `nil` (you want to avoid a released object where the pointer is still assigned).

Comment: @trojanfoe you're right ) maybe ">0" stuck in my head after the array checking on nil)